# External WebBrowser control browsing?

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, mfc

I have idea, i want to code some very specific browser.
That browser gonna run with 2 processes, the first process will have the GUI for the user to navigate and to view the page and the second process will be the one that is doing all the http requests and handling the page clicks events.
I am planning on using MFC WebBrowser control for the job.

I think Internet Explorer version 8/9 has this feature....

Someone can give me hints how to implement this ?
Pipes with classes serialization ?
Any links,resources,hints are welcome :)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE already does this. What is your question? How to use the IE web browser as a control? Please google and ask more specific questions.

Comment: I want GUI of the IE to run in one process and the part that will handle all incoming and outgoing http requests to be in other process.